# Horario en PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando un horario de clases y otros eventos en php y mysql, me esstoy guiando por algunos tutoriales pero muchos de ellos no tiene el campo del número de dia(para que sea un dia especifico) y me pregunto si lo deberia incluir, por ejemplo en el horario se muestran clases que se realizan durante la semana por todo un semestre(en el otro semestre cambian) pero tambien se realizan actividades especiales que aparecen en el horario, por ejemplo una vacunación que se realiza el 18 de julio, algo asi. Por lo que he visto los horarios llenan el horario de la semana automaticamente, sin el numero de dia, ¿como lo hago para un dia especifico? o tambien para poner que una clase se cancela cierto dia. En mi base de datos, tengo el campo que se llenara y los datos son: clase(nombre), profesor, sala, dia, horainicio, horafin. Para las actividades especiales son: evento(nombre), organizador, dia, horainicio, horafin. Gracias y saludos

Comment: La clave está en lo que te dice Iván en su respuesta: **normalizar**. Eso facilitará gestionar las relaciones entre tablas de la mejor manera, evitando duplicidad de datos y demás. Un aspecto a tener en cuenta es que, para controlar datos como fechas/horas, es suficiente con columnas de tipo `DATETIME` donde puedes guardar al mismo tiempo la fecha y la hora, luego, si necesitas sólo la hora, o saber qué día de la semana es, o qué día del año es, puedes usar las funciones que existen para ello, lo mismo para darle formato.

Comment: Gracias, estaba pensando en tener dos horarios, uno para clases  y otro para eventos especiales, para el evento especial deberia poner datetime? Ya que las clases son las mismas y al mismo horario x semestre

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es normalizar tu BD y tener tablas de referencia para ello, por ejemplo, en el caso de los horarios se me ocurre que puedas poner algo asi:

```
mHorarios->eHorarios->dHorarios
```

Donde mHorarios vas a tener la informacion escencial de tu horario, como por ejemplo

```
idmHorario
idmSemestre
fechaInicio
fechaFin
```

para el caso de eHorarios vas a tener los encabezados o eventos excepcionales entonces puedes poner algo asi:

```
ideHorario
idmHorario
idcTipoIncidente
fechaIncidenteInicio
fechaIncidenteFin
```

Mientras que para el dHorarios vas a tener los detalles estaticos de tus horarios, como:

```
iddHorario
idmHorario
idmMaestro
...
fechaFinal
```

Con esto puedes tener un mejor control de todo lo que pase en tu horario, igual espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, por ahora en la bd tengo la tabla cronograma en donde va la clase(fk), el profesor(fk), horainicio, horatermino y sala, eso seria para un bloque de clases, lo que tu me dices es que haga una table de horario, para por ejemplo, el horario semestral y a esa tabla la llene con los bloques de clases(cronograma)? Gracias

Comment: SI, podria funcionar, recuerda que eso es parte de la normalizacion de bases de datos llegando hasta la 3a forma normal, esto nos indica que todas las tablas deben contener solo informacion que le corresponda o este ligada al primer dato, si consideras esto entonces tienes que tu horario se puede dividir en 3 tablas sin ningun problema donde una va a tener los datos del horario nada mas, otro los detalles del horario y otro los eventos del horario  puedes leer [esto](https://programas.cuaed.unam.mx/repositorio/moodle/pluginfile.php/872/mod_resource/content/1/contenido/index.html) para aclarar

Comment: Gracias la normalizacion que tenia era: La tabla cronograma esta compuesta x la clase, sala, profesor, hora inicio, hora termino. Clase, Profesor y sala son FK y las tabla de clase tiene el id,nombre, tipo(fk), profesor tiene id,nombre, apellido y sala tiene id y nombre. O sea que en nirmalizacion, la 3 seria la tabla horario que tiene los cronograms que llenan los bloques de horario?

Comment: Mira, la normalizacion deberia ser objetiva, pero depende mucho de tu experiencia, te recomiendo que cuando normalices lo hagas conforme a tus necesidades, aunque a como te plantee mi respuesta si es algo asi como lo que comentas.